# how to drop data in mongo db using python

Tags: python, mongodb, import

In my mongodb I have around 20K records,
now From the same mongodb I am importing only 500 records in python and now I need to delete those 500 records which I have imported , is it possible to delete those 500 records using python?

my code for importing 500 records

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
con = MongoClient(local host, 27017)
db = con.rssfeeds_db
data = pd.DataFrame(list(db.restdata.find().limit(500)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the _id for each record so that you could tell pymongo which records to delete. For example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
con = MongoClient(localhost, 27017)
db = con.rssfeeds_db

// create a list of the records. each one will be a dict.
records = [x for x in db.restdata.find().limit(500)]

// create a list of the 500 ids so we only need to call the db once
record_ids = [record['_id'] for record in records]

//create your dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(records)

// delete all 500 records at once
db.restdata.delete_many(
    {'_id': 
        {'$in': record_ids}
    },
)
```

Comment: hi @forgetso I am getting error for the above code 

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'deleteMany' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Comment: My bad, it should be delete_many for pymongo (deleteMany in Mongo shell). I've updated the answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)